# How do I auto-fill fields in Access from a linked table?

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables in an Access (2007-2010) database which are linked. I have created forms with a command button in my 'Organisation' form that opens up a new record in my 'Contacts' forms. I would like to automatically fill in some of the fields in the 'Contacts' form from the 'Organisation' form, such as the 'OrganisationName' field, which will be the same information in both forms. Is there a way I can do this? I have spent many hours searching online and have tried various things, but have not found an answer yet! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You don't normally duplicate information in this way, If the contact is linked to the organisation presumably by the OrganisationID as a foreign key then storing it again as a text field is redundant, and troublesome to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behavior you're looking for by setting the `Default Value` property of the text box on the Contacts form to the control on the Organisation form:

```
[Forms]![Organisation]![OrganisationName]
```

This will copy the value from one form to the other.

If you are storing the same values, like OrganisationName, in both your Organisation and Contacts tables, your table structure probably needs some normalisation. You could, for example, have an OrganisationID stored in your Contacts table, and look up all of the relevant Organisation information for display on the Contact form. Somewhere on your Contact form you will have a field, probably a ComboBox, bound to the OrganisationID and that ComboBox's Default Value could be set to the OrganisationID on the Organisation form, which would give you the same result without duplicating the OrganisationName itself in both tables.

Comment: Great, thank you for this, this is exactly what I wanted to do, and is such a simple solution. I am sure my database can do with a lot of tidying up - this is my first one!

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you, @Leah. Please accept the answer.